How to add user input fields on canvas on specific position to get inputs from user in flutter
I have some requirement regarding canvas rendering in that I want to place textfield , radio , checkbox , date picker and other input fields on canvas based on it position received from Json response.
I haven't found any solution or appropriate flow to deal with this requirement

Yeah right canvas in flutter , Need to place textfield and other input fields based on X , Y value received from json

there is a Stack widget for that (with Positioned children)

but how can I implement it with. canvas?

CustomPaint(painter: ..., child: Stack(children: ...)
